# Avoid Double Encoding JSON when Combining two Pandas' to_json Calls

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (nodes and links) that are JSONified by Pandas' to_json call:

```
links = links.to_json(orient='records')
nodes = nodes.to_json(orient='records')
```

The output of these calls seem to be as expected:

Links:

```
[{"source":"Michael Scott", "target":"Jim Halpert", "value":1}]
```

Nodes:

```
[{"id":"Michael Scott"}, {"id":Jim Halpert"}]
```

I then combine these JSON dicts into one object (to be used in a d3 force-directed graph):

```
j = {"nodes":nodes, "links":links}
```

Now I have two problems:

1. The JSON object `j` is double encoded with single quotes around the square brackets

`{'nodes': 
         '[{"id":"Michael Scott"}, {"id":Jim Halpert"}]', 
  'links': 
         '[{"source":"Michael Scott", "target":"Jim Halpert", "value":1}]'
 }`

2. There doesn't seem to be a great way to write this to a file. I can't use the built in path for `to_json` because I have to separate dataframes that have already been JSONified. I tried this:

   `jsonOut = open('test.json', 'w') 
   jsonOut.write(json.dumps(j))`

This results in a double encoded format in the final file as well, just with extra double quotes instead of single quotes.

**Question:** How do I avoid double encoding resulting JSON files when combining two Pandas dataframes that have been JSONified? And how do I write out the resulting file?

Thank you for any insight you might have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pandas method [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) converts to a JSON *string* which is the value added to your outer dictionary `j`.

So this code serializes the `DatFrame` as a `string`:

```
links = links.to_json(orient='records')
```

If you check the type of `links` it wil be a `str`:

```
type(links)
<type 'str'>
```

Try using [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) instead.

Comment: This fixes the issue of double encoding! Thank you very much - apologies for it being such a simple answer. Do you have an idea about the second portion of my question relating to how to write it out?

Comment: Your current method of using `json.dumps()` seems fine; what issue are you having with it?

Comment: You are correct - I lost connectivity to the DB I'm pulling from and made a poor assumption. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could show us more of your code.
I tried to reproduce your issue but I did not run into the same problems as you.
my code:

```
import json
links = [{"source":"Michael Scott", "target":"Jim Halpert", "value":1}]
nodes = [{"id":"Michael Scott"}, {"id":"Jim Halpert"}]
j = {"nodes":nodes, "links":links}
print j
```

my output:

```
{'nodes': [{'id': 'Michael Scott'}, {'id': 'Jim Halpert'}], 'links': [{'source': 'Michael Scott', 'target': 'Jim Halpert', 'value': 1}]}
```

I also generated a json file:[image]

You're problem might how you instanciate links and nodes before the pd.to_json()

Julien

Comment: The initial encoding to a `str` occurs prior to the creation of `j`, during the creation of `links` and `nodes` in fact.   You don't reproduce the issue here as you start with a (hand rolled) and correct definition of the input dictionaries.

Comment: Right, that's why I didn't think including more code would be helpful since the starting place for me is dicts that look like yours, Julien. Yet they are created by `to_json` instead of handmade.

Comment: As FujiApple said, to_json does not create Dict but strings. You should use to_dict to export , or json.loads to convert your string into dict: j = {"nodes": json.loads(nodes), "links":json.loads(links)}